# Passing a PHP variable with fetched data to a JavaScript variable returns NULL or empty

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have an issue with returning the value of a PHP variable in JS. It returns `NULL` or empty instead of returning the age.

**Approach:**

Passing PHP variable with data to a JS variable in a separate file. Display JS variable in an `alert()`. Data was fetched from the database using `fetch_assoc()` in a while loop. Without using Ajax!

**Proposed plan:**

1. Enter a name.
2. Submit.
3. PHP fetches the age associated with that name.
4. age is stored in a PHP variable `dbage`.
5. Passed into JS variable to alert user what their age is.

I am trying to pass `$dbage` from **sampletest.php** to `user` in **sample.php** which will onsubmit display an alert saying: "Your age is blah".

`blah` is `$dbage`, which contains the age. This is for testing. Once I understand why this isn't working, I can move on to sending these JS variables to functions that will do calculations and return back to the DB.

**What I have tried so far..**

1. Trying to catch `echo` using `ob_start()` but that returned `NULL` as well.

   Example:

   ```
      ob_start();
      echo $dbage;
      $output = ob_get_contents();
      ob_end_clean();
   ```
2. Making `$dbage` a global variable. Returns empty.
3. Echo variable outside the `while` loop but that returned `NULL`.

   Example:

   ```
       $dbage = '';
       while( $row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
           $dbage = $row['age'];
       }
       echo $dbage;
   ```

Any suggestions, corrections are appreciated.

**sample.php (index file)**

```
<?php
include 'sampletest.php';
session_start();    
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">    
<body>
     <div id="id03">
      <form class="modal-content" action="sampletest.php" method="post" onsubmit="myFunction()">
        <div class="container">
          <input type="text" id="name" placeholder="Enter name"  name="name">
            <div class="clearfix">
            <button type="submit" class="loggedinbtn" name="load"/>Load
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>    

    <script>
    function myFunction() {
        var user = '<?php echo(json_encode($dbage)); ?>';
        alert("This is a php varible " + user);
    }
    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**sampletest.php**

```
if(isset($_POST['load'])){
    require 'config.php';
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $age = $_POST['age'];
    if(empty($name)) {
        echo "Enter a number";
    }elseif(!preg_match('/^[a-z ]+$/i', $name)){
        echo "Enter a letter, no numbers";
    }else{
        if ($conn->connect_error) {
            die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
            header("location: sample.php?Connect-database=failed");
            exit();
        } 
        $sql = "SELECT name, age FROM results WHERE name= '$name';";
        $result = $conn->query($sql);

        if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
            while( $row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {                    
                 $dbage = $row['age'];
            }
        }
        else{
            echo "0 results";
        }
        $conn->close();
    }    
}
```

Comment: `$data_dbage` not the same as `$dbage`

Comment: Develop with `error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');` and you will see.

Comment: @AbraCadaver That wasn't suppose to be there, was using it for testing

Comment: It shouldn't be `action="sampletest.php"`, because `sampletest.php` doesn't print anything. It should be `action="sample.php"`.

Comment: `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', '1');` are included. No warning, no notice....

Comment: Test sampletest.php alone first.  Does the variable `$dbage` actually contain the value you want?  Once that works, move on to sample.php.  FYI your `<button>` does not have a closing `</button>` after the Load text.  To troubleshoot, setup a button with onClick event pointing to your script.  If that works, it's that your `<form>` setup is wrong.  FYI2: if num_rows is == 0, `$dbage` is not set, it is undefined.

Comment: why do you echo(json_encode($dbage)); instead of just echo $dbage?

Comment: @jonnyjandles `var user = '<?php echo(json_encode($dbage)); ?>';` is already in sample.php

Comment: I asked WHY DO you do that...

Comment: @Nic3500 1) `dbage` does have the value I want. I checked that using var_dump. It outputs `string(2) "22"` 2) in HTML 5 `<button type="submit" class="loggedinbtn" name="save"/>Save` is the same as `<button type="submit" class="loggedinbtn" name="save">Save</button>` 3) I don't get the last FYI...`num_rows is > 0,` not `num_rows is == 0,`
`

Comment: @jonnyjandles Sorry, `json_encode` handles strings better. According to the manual.

Comment: handles strings better than what?

Comment: @Barmar that makes sense but unfortunately still getting NULL. Unrelated question,  when should someone set action to a processing PHP?

Comment: The `action` should be the script that processes the post data and displays the result.

Comment: @jonnyjandles better than a reg echo.

Comment: `sample.php` processes the form data when it does `include 'sampletest.php';`'

Comment: You'll get `NULL` when you load the page the first time, since there's no form data posted yet, so `$dbage` hasn't been set yet. You should get the correct value after you submit the form.

Comment: No, json_encode is to encode into json.  Check the manual -> https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php.  If your $db_age is not a value that can be encoded into json, it will return false.

Comment: Also, I don't see how that could be your whole sampletest.php file since you there seems to be no creation of the $conn

Comment: @jonnyjandles $conn is in the config.php which I required. DB connection is in a separate file :). Should I not do that?

Comment: So, did the answer you marked as correct fix your problem?  Else, why did you mark it as correct?

Comment: @jonnyjandles it did but now I have learn and implement AJAX. Reason stated by _Barmar_ `$dbage` doesn't get set until I submit.

Comment: @Barmar To fix that problem, I need to implement AJAX correct?

Comment: You could just use `if (isset($dbage))`

Comment: THANK YOU GUYS YOU WERE VERY HELPFUL!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your action in the form should be set to sample.php, i think is the first problem. then get rid of the javascript all together.

```
<form class="modal-content" action="sample.php" method="post">
```

then change:

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
    var user = '<?php echo(json_encode($dbage)); ?>';
    alert("This is a php varible " + user);
}
</script>
```

to just

```
<script>
    var user = <?php echo $dbage; ?>;
    alert("This is a php varible " + user);
</script>
```

submitting html forms to PHP does not require javascript at all.

Comment: Definitely a newbie and trying to understand how PHP, JS and HTML interact.

Comment: @MTBthePRO we've all been there. it's confusing at first, but you will get there. understand how forms work without any javascript at first. eventually you will learn how to do AJAX calls with javascript, which can fetch data from PHP without reloading the whole page like a form submission would.

Comment: Yes, that is the next step. AJAX is a must when learning back-end programming. So my issue was directing action incorrectly, using json_encode was not necessary and `' '` before <? and after ?> `'<?php echo $dbage; ?>;'` Reason why I was using `' '` because I read somewhere, you need to use quotation if the variable is a string. Is that correct?

Comment: @MTBthePRO also, one more tip. if you are just fetching data, use GET as your method, and use the corresponding GET global variables. POST is for changes to the database, and will cause warnings to the user if they hit the back button, submitting the same POST request to the server and stuff like that. there is a pattern people use where even on a POST form submission, after the database changes are made, PHP will redirect the user to a page. this way when the user hits the back button, it won't try to submit the same POST twice. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get

Comment: @MTBthePRO when you use something like json_encode(), you should look up what that does, and figure out why someone is using it. json_encode would be for if you were returning a whole PHP object or array full of data to your javascript after an ajax call, and need to turn that object into a string for transmission, then the javascript would turn that JSON string back into an object (a javascript object on the client side), and be able to access any or the properties or array items of the object.

Comment: @MTBthePRO once you have mastered PHP and HTML more, and start trying your hand at AJAX, you should consider using a library to make it easier, such as JQuery. once you have mastered how ajax works, you can start trying your hand at frameworks like REACT/REDUX. that's a ways off though. would be super confusing at your stage I think.

Comment: @MTBthePRO for the above example, you are just having aan HTML form, submit data to the same page, so it loads again, but this time it has the form variables available to it. on that second load, it can then use those variables to find the age. then it just echoes the age out directly into the page that it sends back to the user. you gotta understand the flow of what happens at each step. PHP only executes before the page is sent to the user, then javascript only executes once the page has loaded client side. you were mixing the two as if they were both executing at the same time.

Comment: Thank you for your amazing help and tips for the future! For your last comment, you’re saying “PHP only executes before the page is sent to the user” I am not quite sure what you mean by that.

Comment: @MTBthePRO the user's browser sends a message to the server requesting the page sample.php, the server gets that message, executes the PHP code in sample.php, which generates an HTML page that gets sent back to the user's browser. the browser then receives that page, displays it, and runs any javascript code contained within it.

Comment: @MTBthePRO your PHP code is located on a server that executes it. your javascript code is in the page, and is executed by the browser.

Comment: @MTBthePRO when you submit a form in an HTML page, it not only requests the page contained in the form tag's action attribute, but sends some variables along with it, for PHP to use. those are the GET or POST variables that PHP accesses, that represent the user input into the form.

Comment: Great explanation. THANK YOU!

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see is that the actual query that you're sending is  { name= '$name'  }, try { name=' " . $name . " ' }.